# If in_category not working for multiple single.php pages

Tags: posts, categories, single

I searched far and wide (on here & Google), reading about how to have **multiple single.php pages** for different categories of posts. The consensus was to do something like this:

```
<?php
/*
    Template name: Single
*/
?>
<?php

$post = $wp_query->post;

if ( in_category('blog') ) {
    //echo 'category is 3 which is blog-single';
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/blog-single.php'); 
} 

elseif ( in_category('projects') ) {
    //echo 'category is 4 which is project-single';
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/project-single.php'); 
} 

else {
    //echo 'category is neither of the above so default is selected';
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/project-single.php');
}

?>
```

But for whatever reason this is not working for me. It always goes to the `else` statement when I click on a blog post of a project post. The page above is called `single.php` and the two other pages are named `project-blog.php` & `blog-single.php` exactly.

I attempted to comment out the `include(TEMPLATEPATH..` and just echo some text, but it always would go straight to the `else` no matter which post I click on.

I have triple checked the the category ID is correct for each `if` statement (see image below).

I also tried to make it `is_category` instead of `in_category` as well as also trying to put the category name in place of the category_id (for example blog or projects).

What am I doing wrong? Here's a screen shot of the URL from when drilling into a Category showing that the category_id (tag_id) is indeed correct. I hope this is enough info...

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5gPa.jpg]

**edit:**
I even tried this...

```
if ( in_category('blog') || is_category(blog) || is_category('blog') || in_category(blog) || is_category(3) || is_category('3') || in_category('3') || in_category(3) ) {
```

And I changed my permalinks to include the category in them. So now project-single is working but not blog...

Comment: Even though you're getting the post you're not technically IN 'The Loop' - try passing the post into the function like [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) suggests - so something like this `in_category('blog', $post)` or `in_category('blog', $post->ID)`

Comment: @Howdy_McGee thanks! I see what you're saying, that makes sense. Unfortunately it didn't do the trick. I tried both samples. But I will look into that idea and the docs. I was able to get the `projects` category to work by changing the permalink structure. So worst case scenario I can just do an `IF ELSE` with the `ELSE` being my `blog` category.